# Find start / end of series, perform % difference between them

Tags: r

I have a series of signals at which I which to find the start of the sequence which would be the first `+1` in the `signal column`. When it finds the `first +1`, it is to remember the `Open Price`. It is then to loop through until it finds the `last +1` in the sequence, when it does it will save the `Close Price`. Once both prices are obtained: work out the % difference between the two. `(Close value - Open Value) / Open value`. Continue to loop until next `+1`

An example data / output is below:

```
df <- data.frame(df,output=0)

      Open   Close signal       output
1  1469.25 1455.17      0  0.000000000
2  1455.22 1399.42      0  0.000000000
3  1399.42 1402.11      1  0.000000000
4  1402.11 1403.45      1  0.002879700
5  1403.45 1441.47      0  0.000000000
6  1441.47 1457.60      0  0.000000000
7  1457.60 1438.56      0  0.000000000
8  1438.56 1432.04      0  0.000000000
9  1432.25 1449.68      0  0.000000000
10 1449.68 1465.15      0  0.000000000
11 1465.15 1455.14      0  0.000000000
12 1455.14 1455.90      0  0.000000000
13 1455.90 1445.57      0  0.000000000
14 1445.57 1441.36      0  0.000000000
15 1441.36 1401.68      0  0.000000000
16 1401.53 1410.03      1  0.000000000
17 1410.03 1404.09      1  0.001826532
18 1404.09 1398.56      0  0.000000000
19 1398.56 1360.15      0  0.000000000
20 1360.16 1394.46      1  0.000000000
21 1394.46 1409.28      1  0.036113398
22 1409.28 1409.12      0  0.000000000
23 1409.12 1424.97      0  0.000000000
24 1424.97 1424.37      0  0.000000000
25 1424.37 1424.24      0  0.000000000
26 1424.24 1441.75      0  0.000000000
27 1441.72 1411.71      0  0.000000000
28 1411.70 1416.84      0  0.000000000
29 1416.83 1387.11      0  0.000000000
30 1387.12 1389.94      0  0.000000000
31 1389.94 1402.05      0  0.000000000
32 1402.05 1387.67      0  0.000000000
33 1387.67 1388.25      1  0.000000000
34 1388.26 1346.09      1  0.000000000
35 1346.09 1352.23      1  0.000000000
36 1352.17 1360.69      1  0.000000000
37 1360.69 1353.43      1  0.000000000
38 1353.43 1333.36      1  0.000000000
39 1333.36 1348.05      1 -0.028551449
40 1348.05 1366.42      0  0.000000000
41 1366.42 1379.23      0  0.000000000
```

Using line 33 to 39 as example: 
it finds +1 at line 33 
it saves open price to use later 
loops until last +1 on line 39. 
It then saves the close price .
Now we have both prices . We can perform the % difference between the two.
Continue to loop until next +1 signal

This is my butchered attempt:

```
state <- "off"
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { # loop through data
  if (state == "off") { # off state, loop does nothing until signal = 1
    if (df$signal[i] == 0) {
      next
    } else { 
      open_price <- df$Open[i] # save open price for % calculation
       state <- "on"                   # change state to "on"
    }
  } else if (state == "on") { 
    if (df$signal[i] > 0) { # Find last +1
      close_price <- df$Close[i] # save close price for % calculation
      output <- (close_price - open_price)/ open_price # perform % calculation
      state <- "off" 
  }
  }
}
```

Idea is to have on/off state.. turns on during +1's finds start / end values. % diff calculation, turns off for remainder

Comment: Please edit your post to include what you have tried so far and where you are facing difficulties, potential solutions could build on that. Also search for "R return calcuation", "R xts object",functions `first` and `last` from `xts` package and finally [PerformanceAnalytics package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using functions from the `dplyr` package and `rleid` function from the `data.table` package. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(RunID = data.table::rleid(signal)) %>%
  group_by(RunID) %>%
  mutate(output = ifelse(signal == 0, 0,
                         ifelse(row_number() == n(),
                                (last(Close) - first(Open))/first(Open), 0))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-RunID)
```

#### Input Data

```
dt <- structure(list(Open = c(1469.25, 1455.22, 1399.42, 1402.11, 1403.45, 
1441.47, 1457.6, 1438.56, 1432.25, 1449.68, 1465.15, 1455.14, 
1455.9, 1445.57, 1441.36, 1401.53, 1410.03, 1404.09, 1398.56, 
1360.16, 1394.46, 1409.28, 1409.12, 1424.97, 1424.37, 1424.24, 
1441.72, 1411.7, 1416.83, 1387.12, 1389.94, 1402.05, 1387.67, 
1388.26, 1346.09, 1352.17, 1360.69, 1353.43, 1333.36, 1348.05, 
1366.42), Close = c(1455.17, 1399.42, 1402.11, 1403.45, 1441.47, 
1457.6, 1438.56, 1432.04, 1449.68, 1465.15, 1455.14, 1455.9, 
1445.57, 1441.36, 1401.68, 1410.03, 1404.09, 1398.56, 1360.15, 
1394.46, 1409.28, 1409.12, 1424.97, 1424.37, 1424.24, 1441.75, 
1411.71, 1416.84, 1387.11, 1389.94, 1402.05, 1387.67, 1388.25, 
1346.09, 1352.23, 1360.69, 1353.43, 1333.36, 1348.05, 1366.42, 
1379.23), signal = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Open", 
"Close", "signal"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
"40", "41"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Fantastic - this is looking for powerful using dplyr and data.table rleid. How did you learn how to use these?? Any guides / tutorials?